# How to monitor AWS QLDB in Datadog

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, datadog, amazon-qldb

I'm trying to monitor QLDB in Datadog with its metrics and integrate that with Pagerduty.
Can't find a way to get the metrics of QLDB into Datadog. how can I monitor QLDB?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there isn't a direct QLDB integration in their catalog.
But you should be able to setup custom CloudWatch metrics in Datadog, specific to QLDB. Cross reference the QLDB monitoring guide with Datadog's custom monitoring and alerting for cloudwatch, and you should be able to pull together some QLDB monitoring in Datadog.

https://www.datadoghq.com/monitor-cloudwatch/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/monitoring-automated-manual.html